# YarnRuntimeException file doesnt exist

Tags: hadoop, history, server, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to run a Pig script, getting the error  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exception.YarnRuntimeException): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /tmp/hadoop-yarn.staging/history/done/2015/01/08/000000 does not exits !!!
what does that mean ? shoudl I create it ?  where should I put it ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today and found out YarnRuntimeException is included in the hadoop-yarn-api-2.6.0.jar file. Make sure it's in your class path and you should be good.